# GraphicsMagick with brew

Tags: homebrew

I want to use the GraphicsMagick C API on a Mac. I used brew to install it, but the header files I need to use the API is not available. At least, I am not able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They should be in `/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.26_1/include/GraphicsMagick`.

```
 $ tree -L 3 /usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.26_1/include/
 /usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.26_1/include/
 └── GraphicsMagick
     ├── Magick++
     │   ├── Blob.h
     │   ├── CoderInfo.h
     │   ├── Color.h
     │   ├── Drawable.h
     │   ├── Exception.h
     │   ├── Geometry.h
     │   ├── Image.h
     │   ├── Include.h
     │   ├── Montage.h
     │   ├── Pixels.h
     │   ├── STL.h
     │   └── TypeMetric.h
     ├── Magick++.h
     ├── magick
     │   ├── analyze.h
     │   ├── api.h
     │   ├── attribute.h
     │   ├── average.h
     │   ├── blob.h
     │   ├── cdl.h
     │   ├── channel.h
     │   ├── color.h
     │   ├── color_lookup.h
     │   ├── colormap.h
     │   ├── colorspace.h
     │   ├── command.h
     │   ├── common.h
     │   ├── compare.h
     │   ├── composite.h
     │   ├── compress.h
     │   ├── confirm_access.h
     │   ├── constitute.h
     │   ├── decorate.h
     │   ├── delegate.h
     │   ├── deprecate.h
     │   ├── describe.h
     │   ├── draw.h
     │   ├── effect.h
     │   ├── enhance.h
     │   ├── error.h
     │   ├── forward.h
     │   ├── fx.h
     │   ├── gem.h
     │   ├── gradient.h
     │   ├── hclut.h
     │   ├── image.h
     │   ├── list.h
     │   ├── log.h
     │   ├── magic.h
     │   ├── magick.h
     │   ├── magick_config.h
     │   ├── magick_types.h
     │   ├── memory.h
     │   ├── module.h
     │   ├── monitor.h
     │   ├── montage.h
     │   ├── operator.h
     │   ├── paint.h
     │   ├── pixel_cache.h
     │   ├── pixel_iterator.h
     │   ├── plasma.h
     │   ├── profile.h
     │   ├── quantize.h
     │   ├── random.h
     │   ├── registry.h
     │   ├── render.h
     │   ├── resize.h
     │   ├── resource.h
     │   ├── shear.h
     │   ├── signature.h
     │   ├── statistics.h
     │   ├── symbols.h
     │   ├── texture.h
     │   ├── timer.h
     │   ├── transform.h
     │   ├── type.h
     │   ├── utility.h
     │   └── version.h
     └── wand
         ├── drawing_wand.h
         ├── magick_wand.h
         ├── pixel_wand.h
         ├── wand_api.h
         └── wand_symbols.h

 4 directories, 82 files
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a quick question. Aren't they supposed to be symlinked to /usr/local or something like that?

Comment: The problem is that I specify the exact header file, but then the header file references other header files as 'magick/magick_config.h', but that is not the right path. Then the program does not compile. I remember that in Linux, one could add folders to C_INCLUDE_PATH, but that does not seem to be working with mac. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just use the GM tools, so I can't help you with the programming problem. But you can look at [build-configuration](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/INSTALL-unix.html#build-configuration) on GM's site to see what is possible. I'm guessing you need to set the library path to `/usr/local/Cellar/graphicsmagick/1.3.26_1/include/GraphicsMagick`.

Comment: There's also [Programming](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/programming.html)